# Splitting KMZ file into two files using QGIS?

Tags: qgis, kmz

I have a KMZ file that contains about 10,500 features.
- My mapping application only allows 10,000 (a google api limit)
- So how do I split the KMZ file into two files?
- Example, file_A = 5,000 and file_B = 5,500

In QGIS v3, I can open the file, then open the Attribute Table:
- I see the 10,500 lines..
- I can select the first 5,000 lines..
- But how do I save these to a new KMZ file?

Or maybe delete the last 5,500 and save to a new file_A..?

Surely there is a way to quickly/easily break a KMZ into two files?

Comment: Your problem is considering KMZ a file format. It isn't. KML is the format, with a zip compression applied. You cannot split a compressed file without uncompressing first. Due to the volume nature of KML, splitting requires additional work before the resulting KMLs can be recompressed. Please [Edit] the question to specify what you have tried so far, and take the [Tour] to better understand how things work here. Welcome to GIS SE.

Answer (score 4):

Open select by attribute dialog for the actual layer from the toolbar.
[image: select by attribute]

Select the first 10000 records using $id from the record group.

[image: Selection expression]

Select *Save as* from the popup menu of the layer and check save only selected features. Input a name for the new layer.

[image: Save as]

Invert the selection of the layer.

[image: Invert selection]

Finally *Save as* the second part of the layer.